# SUM dynamically added fields in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a table where I can dynamically add rows to a table. But I'd like to be able to include a subtotal at the bottom of the table. So far I have something like:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" name="shipment_details[charge][]"/>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" name="shipment_details[charge][]"/>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" name="shipment_details[charge][]"/>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" name="shipment_details[charge][]"/>
<input type="text" class="qty1" value="" name="shipment_details[charge][]"/>
```

But this doesn't work when I play with in JSFiddle, so I am curious if I am doing the name portion of the javascript wrong, or if I am just not doing it all together. I should say that my text field for where to "deposit" the subtotal is the following:

```
<input type="text" readonly name="freightBillSubtotal" id="freightBillSubtotal">
```

Comment: Show us your JSFiddle, since the code posted should work https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/431/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you , you want to get sum of all values in inputs?!
 try it:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]', function() { 
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]').each(function(index,elem){
      let value = $(elem).val();
      if(typeof value ==="number"){
         sum += +value;
      }
    });
$('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum);
  console.log(sum)
});
```

I recommend to use class selectors instead complex selector. Code will be simple.